# Cordova Inappbrowser:Custom address bar while loading a webpage

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have successfully loaded a webpage in my app using inappbrowser plugin in cordova android.I have disabled the address bar using this line code

```
window.open('http://www.sample.com/','_self','location=no');`
```

Now i want to display  a title with a name (eg:when shows a login page title name should be Login)instead of address bar.Is it possible?.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this function to get space for title and rename it by JS.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
     var ref = window.open('http://www.sample.com/','_self','location=no');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', css_changein_inappbrowser_Function);
}
function css_changein_inappbrowser_Function() {
        ref.insertCSS({
            //do some work for title eg: title {some dimensions} in css
        }, function() {
            alert("space given for title");
            document.title = "Some new title text";// to change title of your own.
        }
    }
```